# Mettersi a parte e mettersi da parte

Tags: word-choice, difference

Che differenza c'è tra "mettersi a parte" e "mettersi da parte". Ho cercato nel dizionario ma non ho trovato la differenza.

Questo è il contesto. Ancora non capisco.

> Rocchina aiutera tua madre affinche capisca quanto mi metto da parte e ti aspetto  il gruppo compresa Francesca la figlia di Loiacono si è proposto di aiutarci e mi ha detto che non è detto che davvero non possa essre un futuro reale per noi ma che dobbiamo andarci piano affidiamoci amore

Grazie.

Comment: Ci fai un esempio di frase in cui hai letto o sentito “mettersi a parte”? Non lo ho presente. Non sarà forse “mettere [qualcuno] a parte [di qualcosa]”?

Comment: Jack, il testo che riporti sembra piuttosto sgrammaticato, oltre a essere del tutto privo di punteggiatura. È forse un testo privato, come una lettera o simili? Se sì, avresti fatto meglio a togliere i nomi di persona. Comunque qui “mi metto da parte” significa sicuramente “mi metto in disparte, rimango indietro, non intervengo”.

Comment: Grazie @DaG. Come hai fatto a raggiungere questa conclusione?

Comment: Quale conclusione? Sulle sgrammaticature del testo, sulla mancanza della punteggiatura, sulla scarsa opportunità di divulgare testi privati o sul significato di “mi metto da parte”? Se è quest'ultimo, non è una conclusione, è che in italiano non può significare altro.

Comment: Insomma non ho ancora capito cosa significa. Volevo sapere se la persona che si mette da parte significa che cessa di essere in un rapporto o in comunicazione. La persona che scrive è della Puglia.

Comment: Si, è un testo privato del quale non ho capito ancora il senso.

Answer (score 2):

### ITA

Qualche esempio di frase aiuterebbe a rispondere, può dipendere dal contesto. Generalmente "a parte" significa "separatamente".
"Mettere da parte" invece significa "mettere via", "mettere in un altro luogo", in genere con il significato implicito di "conservare" poi l'oggetto o di "trascurare".

Es: "ho messo 500€ da parte per andare in vacanza", vuol dire che ho *risparmiato* quei soldi.

### ENG

Some example would have been useful so to answer correctly, since the meaning may depend on the context. Generally speaking "a parte" means "separately".
"Mettere da parte" is like "to put apart" or even "save", "put away", "disregard", "overlook".

Comment: Sicuro di “apparte”?

Comment: Ho controllato, molti ritengono che "apparte" sia scorretto (penso sia una forma di toscanismo), probabilmente dovuto al fatto che nel parlato si raddoppia la p. alcuni [dizionari](http://dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?lemma=apparte) però riportano entrambe le forme.

Comment: *Mettere qcn a parte di qcs* significa anche [*far sapere, rendere partecipe*](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/mettere-a-parte). La forma riflessiva suona un po' strana però.